# get 50 search results per search in selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

When I open a chrome window from selenium and make a get request, the number of results that are being displayed are 10 on google.
Is there a way to get 50 results per page?
Or is there a way to modify the string such that it will fetch 50 results?.
Below is my code, please help me

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=some random string'
driver.get(url)
```

Now, when I execute the above code, it opens chrome and fetches 10 results.
Is there a way to get 50 results out of the search string?
If not in selenium, is there any other way to achieve it?
Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here's it:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(
    "https://www.google.com/search?q=some random string&num=200&start=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8")
```